# How to select a row from array in column in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select a row from my table where the "user id" is equal to some userid, but my columns are an array. How can I select on it?

[image: Image of MySQL Page]

Comment: for array which language you use here ?

Comment: Try FIND_IN_SET https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

Comment: MySQL has no type called "array" so I don't understand the question.  I do see strings with commas which is usually an indicator that the data model needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * from table_name where FIND_IN_SET(@user_id,user_id) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

are you expecting something like this

```
select * from table_name where userid=@userid
```

Comment: i have array in column and i want to select from column but i cant select from array in sql

Answer (score 0):

Try this Query..

```
select * from table where CONCAT(',', userid, ',') like '%,@yourid,%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this mysql

```
select * from table_name where FIND_IN_SET('%@userid%',userid);
```